# Set lerp to over time. in MS

Tags: c#, .net

I am very confused on how exactly I use vector3.Lerp()

I am trying to move an object from Point A to Point B over time.

```
Vector3 goal = Vector3.Lerp(object.position, player.Position, 5000);
NAPI.Entity.SetEntityPosition(object.handle, goal);
```

I am not sure what the last param in Lerp represents, if it is "time" or if it is "distance". No matter what I put there, it always instantly teleports the game object from A to B. I am NOT using UnityEngine this is a MOD for a game.
so using things like time.DeltaTime or transform are not available for me.

The goal is to try and figure out how to move from A to B over a set time. For instance Move the object from A to B over a 5 seconds timespan, not instantly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what the last param in Lerp represents

Whenever you're in that situation, [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is almost always the first place to look. In this case, we get this information:

> When t = 0 returns a. When t = 1 returns b. When t = 0.5 returns the point midway between a and b.

Remember this doesn't just run once. You can't just call the method and let it handle the entire animation for you. You have to redraw the scene numerous times, where you calculated the new position each time. At each new draw, think about how much time (`t`) has passed since the animation started vs how much time you want the entire animation to take (`T`), and use the ratio `t/T` as your argument.

Comment: But even if I set it to 0.5 it still set it at the endPos instantly, not midway between.

Comment: Make sure to read the part at the end. Somewhere, you're calling SetEntityPosition() to match the player.position right away, before the animation finishes.

Comment: Could I just use an integer as time? since I don't have deltaTime. Also, if I take time completely out of the equation, and just set it Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, 0.5); it still goes all the way to endPos and not .5 of it.

Comment: No I just one function that I am calling one time, It is called MoveObject(object, player, duration){Vector3 goal = Vector3.Lerp(object.position, player.Position, 0.5);
NAPI.Entity.SetEntityPosition(object.handle, goal);}

Comment: So theoretically, I am setting the objects position to = goal, and goal should equal halfway between the points, right?

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

DeltaTime is usually used in the last number... basically it's the amount you want to move each call (1 is all the way)
so...  0.016 would make it take ~1 second at 60 updates per second

Comment: I am not using game engine here, I am in standard .net c# I don't have update functions or anything that calls every frame. The lerp is working now, so If I set to 0.5 if midway, but if I want a speed of say 5f how do I create a time, increase that lerp distance for 5f?

Comment: a speed of 5f doesnt mean anything. The question is how long you want it to take, and how many times per second are you calling the function. If you're trying to move something a certain number of pixels at a time, lerp is not the way to go.